# How to call a the activity method finish() from the Application object?

Tags: android, android-context, activity-finish

I have a piece of code to delete an Item in database. I am calling the same code from two different activities. So to avoid code repetition, I want to shift the code to the Application object. The code in one of the activities looks like this:

```
private void deleteItem() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity1.this);
    alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle);
    alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage);
    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {
                    final DbHelper db = new DbHelper(Activity1.this);
                    AsyncTask<Long, Void, Object> deleteTask = new AsyncTask<Long, Void, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground(Long... params) {
                            db.deleteItem(params[0]);
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    };
                    deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });
                }
            });
    alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
}
```

Now to put it in application object, I changed the function to public, gave it two parameters for input: Context and rowID. But in the onPostExecute method of AsyncTask I have to close the activity. In the activity, I did this by finish(). How do I do it in this context? I have attached the code in application object also.

```
public void deleteItem(final Context context, final long rowID) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle);
    alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage);
    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {
                    final DbHelper db = new DbHelper(context);
                    AsyncTask<Long, Void, Object> deleteTask = new AsyncTask<Long, Void, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground(Long... params) {
                            db.deleteItem(params[0]);
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                            finish();
                            }
                    };
                    deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });
                }
            });
    alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
}
```

Comment: Just put this line `((Activity)context).finish();`

Comment: I had tried that! Eclipse still underlines it red : Activity cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Just import android activity class. It will do in one short code line. Don't need to write the classes again. Its not a big woo for casting context in Activity. Its also OOP fundamental..

Comment: @user370305 - are u sure ? maybe you cast ContextThemeWrapper  to Activity ? or Service to Activity ??  or .even Application ???.. very bad idea :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to do is fundamentally not a good idea.

Outside of the Activity code, there are no guarantees that the activity still exists - the memory manager may have cleaned it up, the user may have pressed Back etc.

The final design decision is up to you but I advise you to consider if this is really necessary.

A little redundancy is okay in my opinion if it leads to more program stability and reliability.

Comment: @AnupCowkur - if Activity is not exist then your AlertDailog never became Visible..

Comment: @user370305 You are right. Calling `deleteItem()` itself will lead to a crash in that case. Even more reason not to do this.

Answer (score 5):

`Context` can be cast to `Activity` :

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
```

And than just use :

```
activity.finish();
```

Comment: Yes, its like `((Activity)context).finish();`

Comment: I stumbled across _Context can be cast to Activity_. Of course, this cannot be true in itself; otherwise, Context would have to subclass Activity, or all Context objects would have to be Activity. Both is not the case. You should rather suggest that the first parameter is changed from Context to Activity such that it's clear that it's called with the Activity object. -- Aaaahh, typical StackOverflow; simple yet wrong answers get upvoted... ;)

Comment: @user1971924 You may be doing it, but the OP has no reason to do it like this, and the answer did not mention the constraints which apply to this solution -- the OP does _not_ include any code which calls `deleteItem()` so without informing him that it only works when he passes an Activity object as the first parameter, instead claiming that _Context can be cast to Activity_, it's simply not a good or even correct answer.

Comment: @EvZ No need to be sorry. I never said the code wouldn't work. I just said the answer contains wron pieces of information; and it does. I can live with you following your own suboptimal suggestions.

Comment: @EvZ _Activity extends Context_ It sure does. So what?

Comment: @Class Stacker Ok. Will keep this in mind for future interactions.

Comment: @Class Stacker sorry,missed the point of the question.Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of shifting it to Application, create a BaseActivity(which extends Activity class) class, all your activities extend BaseActivity ..  and common code will be place in BaseActivity

Comment: To access common code of a class its not mandatory to make .java class an Activity by extending it. It will give the class full features of Activity which would be unnecessary.

Comment: @John We're talking about a class which is derived from Activity anyways.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake...I thought he is separating the class and using a  non activity to do the job.

Comment: @ClassStacker - Ok, but I think OP has already written a code, now he just want to finish() the activity with easy and short solution.

Comment: @user370305 Maybe. Maybe not. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, add activity instance as well

```
public void deleteItem(final Context context, Activity activity,final long rowID){
activity.finish();
}
```

Comment: Okay but why have Context and Activity if you have the choice?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to call `Application.finish()` like in C# . You can use method like this :
`Activityname.finish();`

It's good solution. 
I hope I helped.

Comment: Aktywnosc is the name of your activity.